# UiAutomator. How to access to NAF elements?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have some problem with identifying locators for my tests. I've used `UIAutomatorViewer` to check if element has some unique property. And then i've found that element is inaccessible 
`( NAF = true )`. I have no source code of the application and can't get it that's why I'm asking your help.

How can i get access to this element using **UIAutomator** ?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

> Optionally, click on the Toggle NAF Nodes button to see UI components that are not accessible to the uiautomator testing framework. Only limited information may be available for these components

This is taken from the android uiautomator guide. [HERE](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)

---

*Update (2016-05-26): the current version of the official guide (linked above) no longer mentions "NAF Nodes".  A version of the documentation [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) contains the description quoted above.*